# Custom multi-key shortcuts on Mac OS

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently I'm using a Pok3r keyboard. The keyboard comes with custom shortcuts baked in. I however wanted to buy another keyboard, which is not a pok3r. My question is, is it possible to program the shortcuts in Mac OS for it to work with other keyboards?

Some examples:

- Caps Lock => FN
- FN + W => Play
- FN + E => Next
- FN + S => Volume Down
- FN + J/K/L/I => Arrow keys

I remember using something like Karabiner, however that does not work anymore on Sierra. I looked at Karabiner Elements, and it seems it's still early in development, and can't do the above key combinations yet.

So are there any alternatives? If it is possible with Elements, are there any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it isn't easily answered here.
After looking around some more, I saw that there currently for Mac OS Sierra there's no alternative for Karabiner-Elements that does the things stated above.

I did however find that although multi-key shortcuts is not officially supported, there were people who were able to hard code it into the program. Here's a [Github Repo](https://github.com/jrolfs/Karabiner-Elements/tree/fn-ijkl-arrows) that does this for IJKL arrow keys.

This seems to be the solution at this moment, until it is added in the GUI of Karabiner-Elements.